# What is the purpose of "your" in "your honour" or "your majesty" or "your highness" or "your grace"?

Tags: honorifics

I'm not asking [why "your honour" is used](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40692/why-do-we-write-the-name-of-judges-in-a-strange-way) to address judges. I'm asking why "your" is used. When I say "Your car", "your self-respect" or "your peace of mind", I'm talking of something that belongs to someone. Even if "honour", "majesty", "highness" or "grace" is a quality of the person you are referring to, when addressing the person I'd be inclined to use the adjective "**Honourable** George", "**Majestic** George", (I don't know what to say other than "High George" :-) ), "**Gracious** George".
You'd never see anyone saying "Your Doctor George" or "Your Mr. George". It just sounds silly.
So why is **"your"** used?

**Update:** From the comments [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/504546/2294), and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/why-is-it-your-majesty-but-my-lord), it appears to be a metonymy or as @tchrist mentioned: "*Because it is too intimate to use the second person to address someone that important so directly. The style of instead addressing that elevated person's "grace" as a form of courteous address allowed for the use of more distancing third person forms*". Later, @Lambie mentions: "*...addresses the person's station, not the person directly. It's as if there were a cloud around the person of grace, highness or majesty, and that is what is being addressed*".

Comment: It seems that you have your answer. So, in effect, you are asking it again...

Comment: Honestly, I don't have the answer. While the comments that attempt to explain it are somewhat convincing, I'm not fully convinced that it properly explains "your". That's why I updated the question instead of deleting it. Hoping it gets answered eventually.

Comment: It's because **you don't address these people directly**. You address their majesty or honor or grace or highness. It's easy to understand.